# Dojo Drag and Drop

Tags: javascript, dojo, drag-and-drop

I urgently need to write a javascript code for drag and drop using dojo. Please provide me link containing the right code for the same. I just want the simple functionality that items from 1 container can be dropped to items to another container. Nothing decorative. I have goggled it but not getting it right .

Comment: You mean Javascript OR Java? JSP actually stands for JavaServerPages, which is not the same thing as javascript.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example: if you want to drag and drop li's inside an ul you can do so like this:
HTML:

```
<ul id="list">
  <li class="dojoDndItem">content</li>
  <li class="dojoDndItem">content</li>
  <li class="dojoDndItem">content</li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
dojo.require("dojo.dnd.Source");

dojo.addOnLoad(function(){
  new dojo.dnd.Source("list");
});​
```

That's it. Done. Here's a jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/xFcuB/

You can add all kinds of sugar to the while thing. Many many more info here: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/dnd.html#dojo-dnd

Comment: Thanks for that koenp.. It really works great.. Can u suggest something where i can drag a particular item(image, text anything) from one container and drop it in another container ? Like here we are traversing items in a list only. I want it that it moves from 1 container to another ? Thanks.

Comment: Hi thanks for the fiddle. I've increased it to add a `Target`. http://jsfiddle.net/xFcuB/209/

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example: if you want to drag and drop from one container to another container:

**HTML**

```
<div dojoType="dojo.dnd.Source" id="listNode" class="container1">
   <div dojoType="dojo.dnd.Source" class="dojoDndItem movableContainer">A container</div>
   <div class="dojoDndItem">Item 1</div>
   <div class="dojoDndItem">Item 2</div>
   <div class="dojoDndItem">Item 3</div>
</div>
<br>
<div dojoType="dojo.dnd.Source" class="container1">
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
dojo.require("dojo.dnd.Source");
```

**CSS**

```
.dojoDndItem { padding:3px; }
.movableContainer { border: 1px solid #aaa; }
.movableContainer div { margin-left: 5em; }
.container1 { border-radius: 8pt 8pt 8pt 8pt; border:1px solid #aaa; padding: 1em 3em; cursor: pointer; }
.container2 {position:inherit;border-radius: 8pt 8pt 8pt 8pt; border:1px solid #aaa; padding: 1em 3em;cursor: pointer; }
#listNode { background: #ddd; }
```

And your are done.That's the magic.Here's a jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/V5yBs/

And I hope this is what you want. enjoy

Comment: And insert items dynamically to an existing source: http://jsfiddle.net/V5yBs/54/

Comment: @AnatoliyArkhipov How do you add your code to a templated widget?  Basically to drag and drop item to another widget?  I tried bu something is wrong - see http://stackoverflow.com/q/37308974/1104770

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2011/12/05/dojo-drag-n-drop-redux/